# Returning different versions of set of data

Tags: c#, refactoring, factory-pattern

So I have a class with a static method that uses EF to retrieve certain set of mailing lists and maps to the class.

```
 public static List<MailingList> GetMailingListsForUser(IUsersAccess user, IProspectorDataSource db )
 {
    return db.MailingLists.Where(x => x.UserID == user.UserID).ToList()
        .Select(y => new MailingList(y, db) ).ToList();
 }
```

Now though I have a proc that will return the MailingList plus some extra stuff. I don't want to add these extra columns (which will be used in other sections and areas of functionality) to this class. What is the best way to address this?

I am thinking a Factory Pattern that will generate a different class that implements different contracts (interfaces) based on whats needed. Going to try implement it and will post code/working when completed.

Was wondering what other people have done in instances like this and if there are any better ways to address this.

**Edit:** (some extra information to help people understand what I mean).

`public class MailingList
    {
        public int MailingListID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public List<MailingListAddress> MailingListAddresses { get; set; }`

That is the definition of an object that we return. Now there is a new instance where I am going to return some extra columns from a proc and map to MailingList. So I could just add the properties to here but the issue is MailingListAddresses will be null as they will not be returned by the stored proc. So is there a way to map to specific properties and not have to return null for MailingListAddresses to the front end every time.

Comment: Added some extra explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by a senior developer who ended up going with the factory pattern. I will add the code when I get back to work :)